# How can I connect to the store in non-react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I would like to connect to the store in non-react components. My main problem is that the when i try to `getState` or `dispatch` in a non-react class like this: `createStoreWithApi(api).dispatch(isLoading(true))` this will create a new instance of the store, and I just want to modify the already created store. And I know that I would have to avoid having the store as a function.

Is it possible to set the `withExtraArgument`after the store is created? Problem is that I cant just import the **api** in my store file, because I need to fetch the api from the backend first.

This is how my store set-up looks like:

```
const createStoreWithApi = (api: IApi, initialState?: {}) => {
  const middlewares = [
    thunkMiddleware.withExtraArgument({
      api
    })
  ];
  const enhancer = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
  return createStore(rootReducer, initialState!, enhancer);
};
```

Would love some advice

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single instance of store in a `create-store.js` file that holds onto the store singleton. Then import that instance into all files that need access to it for `store.getState` and `store.dispatch`.

```
// create-store.js
let store = null;

export const createStoreWithApi = (api: IApi, initialState?: {}) => {
  const middlewares = [
    thunkMiddleware.withExtraArgument({
      api
    })
  ];
  const enhancer = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
  store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState!, enhancer);
};

export default store;
```

In your entrypoint file, you can run `createStoreWithApi` once with `api` and `initialState`.

```
// index.js
import { createStoreWithApi } from "./create-store";

// init store
createStoreWithApi("api string", {...initialState});
```

And in all other files that need access to the store:

```
import store from "./create-store";

const state = store.getState();
```

As far as setting the API value. I'd recommend setting that in the store with a new reducer action.  Then your middleware and other components will have access to it via `const state = store.getState();`.  Then you don't have to worry about initializing your store with it.  And your components `store.dispatch(setAPI("new api string"))` then `store.dispatch(isLoading(true))`.  And your middleware making the calls can run `store.getState()` and get the current api value before making a backend call.